# How to get a .BIN extension for a file name in a cmd, obtained from a variable off a text file (using powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell, for-loop, foreach

I have the device ID of my drives captured into a text file and I am able to read each ID and pass into a command as a variable, but not able to pass it as $variable.bin file.
I have a software, which needs certain inputs to generate the log.

Let me give an example:

- Text File content: (random serial numbers)

  abc123124324,
  abc234543543,
  abc354354354,
  .
  .

I want to pass the above serial numbers into a command, so I used the following loop:

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content $filePath ) {
    Write-Host "Generating info for $line"
    C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\software.exe -K -o sup -f **${line}.bin** -n $line
    }
```

===
I need to pass each serial number as serialnumber.bin, but its giving an error as its not able to add .bin

Note: For another command (which does not require the use of .bin) the below code works fine:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\software.exe -K ${line}_log.zip -n $line
```

Not sure how to add a .bin extension.
Please help!!

Comment: Surround in quotes `"$line.bin"`

Comment: Hi @Raven, what  the double starts (**) are meaning. Stars are not allowed in file names. Ca you give the error you encounter.

Comment: You're looking for `"${line}.bin"`, as @Daniel points out. Without the enclosing `"..."`, PowerShell treats it as a _property access_, i.e. it looks for property `.bin` on whatever object is stored in variable `${line}`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: @JPBlanc, I think the `**` were just for emphasis, to highlight the place in the code where the problem occurs.